# Cannot install set-monad package in brand new GHC installation

Tags: haskell, cabal

I just have installed GHC and Cabal. I'm getting stuck installing `set-monad` package. My setting is:

```
xxx:~$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2

xxx:~$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.0.0.1
compiled using version 2.0.1.0 of the Cabal library 

xxx:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

When I'm trying to install the package I get:

```
xxx:~$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org

xxx:~$ cabal install set-monad
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring set-monad-0.3.0.0...
Building set-monad-0.3.0.0...
Failed to install set-monad-0.3.0.0
Build log ( /home/incud/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.2/set-monad-0.3.0.0-3UdszwszaTh17UtmYfmrwd.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-12518/set-monad-0.3.0.0'
Configuring set-monad-0.3.0.0...
Preprocessing library for set-monad-0.3.0.0..
Building library for set-monad-0.3.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.Set.Monad   ( Data/Set/Monad.hs, dist/build/Data/Set/Monad.o )

Data/Set/Monad.hs:210:10: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Semigroup’
    |
210 | instance Semigroup (Set a) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-12518/set-monad-0.3.0.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
set-monad-0.3.0.0-3UdszwszaTh17UtmYfmrwd failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Am I missing something? There aren't any further information on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.3.0.0/set-monad.cabal) about installing the package.

Comment: `set-monad`'s dependency bounds have been fixed. See e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.3.0.0/revisions/

Answer (score 1):

This was introduced in [da3ee07](https://github.com/giorgidze/set-monad/commit/da3ee07f69bf1fae13c57b20d65215e474de79c3), which changed the set-monad package from the [old-style `Monoid` to current `Semigroup`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid). Unfortunately, that commit didn't think of keeping backwards compatibility as well, so that `set-monad-0.2` works *only* with GHC<8.4 and `set-monad-0.2` only with GHC>8.2. Worse, that wasn't made explicit in the version bounds.

This is already subject of [a pull request](https://github.com/giorgidze/set-monad/pull/3), however it's never been merged.

Simple solution: install `set-monad-0.2`.

Comment: (Probably the sentence that starts "Unfortunately" should mention two different versions of `set-monad`.)